# Issue reading / writing specific lines within a log file in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I am attempting to print a line that contains a word from within a log file.

I have done some research and as of yet not found a good way to implement this.

I currently have this code:

```
FileInput = open(FILE, "r", encoding='utf-8')

for line in FileInput:
    if "DATA: " in line:
        print line
```

After looking around this seems be the way most people are doing it but I get the following error: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found.

I know the set length from "DATA:" and the line ends with a hexadecimal value of 0A.

Comment: "a hexadecimal value of 0A" -- you mean a newline? And is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Yes as in a new line. I didn't know what would be the best way to carve the data out, in hex or by line? It is Python 3.

Comment: In Python 3 you should be saying `print(line)`, else you'll get a `SyntaxError`. I've got the feeling that this is not the exact code you're using.

Comment: show us the file you are trying to open and the complete stacktrace when you try to execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your FILE variable does not contain a proper string (can we see the value of that? can you do "print(FILE)" before trying to open the file and paste here the result?), or the file is not encoded in a way that is compatible with utf-8. Try opening it in a good editor (like jEdit or Notepad++) and see what the editor tells you it is, then specify that encoding instead of utf.

Comment: There was a corruption within the SQLite file that contained the variable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks Zeki, can you formally accept the answer then? just click on the check box outline to the left of the answer. :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(FILE, encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
```

Take a look here [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode)

Comment: Thank you for your help RanRag but unfortunately I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FileInput = open(FILE, "r")
for line in FileInput:
    if "DATA: " in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Ive tried all variations possible but still getting the same error on the FileInput section.

Thank you for your help.